# Twitter4J - 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect

Tags: twitter4j

I'm playing around with the Twitter4J API and am getting the  401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect when using the `createFriendship` method.

I obtain an instance of Twitter as follows:

```
protected Twitter getApi(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String secret) {
        AccessToken token = new AccessToken(accessToken, secret);
        return new TwitterFactory().getOAuthAuthorizedInstance(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token);
}
```

Once obtained I can successfully use the updateStatus method to tweet something. However when I try to execute the createFriendship method I get the following error even though the status updates are working fine

> Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is 401:Authentication
>   credentials were missing or incorrect.
>   {"request":"\/1\/friendships\/create.json?screen_name=[user]","error":"Incorrect
>   signature"}
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[564a75a9-01c7e75c],
>   statusCode=401, retryAfter=0,
>   rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.5}

In the above error the screen_name=[user] the [user] section is replaced with the correct Twitter screen name.

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a simple problem with 2 different versions of Twitter4J on the classpath!